# Spring not null validation throwing HttpMessageNotReadableException instead of MethodArgumentNotValidException in kotlin

Tags: spring, rest, validation, kotlin

I'm making and simple application in Kotlin using Spring but I'm having a problem with the validation.

I have this entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
data class Category(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long?,
        @field:NotNull @field:NotEmpty val name: String)
```

And my controller function like this:

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun create(@Valid @RequestBody category: Category): ResponseEntity<Category>
```

`create` have some code, but it is irrelevant for the question, my problem is with the request body validation. If I send a category with an empty name field, it is thrown a `MethodArgumentNotValidException` exception, but if I send null to the field `name`, the exception thrown `HttpMessageNotReadableException` instead. Does anyone knows if it is possible to make passing null to a field marked with `@NotNull` to also throw `MethodArgumentNotValidException` in Kotlin.

Answer (score 5):

So your problem is you specify the name field as not nullable, by default jackson module for kotlin will check it and throw `HttpMessageNotReadableException` which cause by `MissingKotlinParameterException` during json mapping process. If you mark `name` filed as nullable json mapping will passed and get to the spring validation phase with `@Valid` then we will get `MethodArgumentNotValidException`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
data class Category(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long?,
    @field:NotNull @field:NotEmpty val name: String?)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can handle this issue by providing `HttpMessageNotReadableException` handler
and then checking if the underlying cause is `MissingKotlinParameterException`.

After that, you can provide custom validation error. I'm using `zalando-problem`, so syntax is a bit different from vanilla spring, but you get the idea:

```
    @ExceptionHandler
    override fun handleMessageNotReadableException(
        exception: HttpMessageNotReadableException,
        request: NativeWebRequest
    ): ResponseEntity<Problem> {
        // workaround
        val cause = exception.cause
        if (cause is MissingKotlinParameterException) {
            val violations = setOf(createMissingKotlinParameterViolation(cause))
            return newConstraintViolationProblem(exception, violations, request)
        }
        return create(Status.BAD_REQUEST, UnableToReadInputMessageProblem(), request)
    }

    private fun createMissingKotlinParameterViolation(cause: MissingKotlinParameterException): Violation {
        val name = cause.path.fold("") { jsonPath, ref ->
            val suffix = when {
                ref.index > -1 -> "[${ref.index}]"
                else -> ".${ref.fieldName}"
            }
            (jsonPath + suffix).removePrefix(".")
        }
        return Violation(name, "must not be null")
    }
```

This way you get get nice output with proper constraint error.

You may try to declare `@ExceptionHandler` for `MissingKotlinParameterException` directly (though I've tried, but it didn't some reason), but I can't guarantee it'll work.

Code samples for path parsing are taken from [here](https://github.com/valiktor/valiktor/blob/622a2b967d152edcea0056716d222d660013a636/valiktor-spring/valiktor-spring/src/main/kotlin/org/valiktor/springframework/web/controller/MissingKotlinParameterExceptionHandler.kt#L51)