# MethodArgumentNotValidException not thrown in case of validation fail

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest, spring-validator

I'm trying to implement validation in Spring REST by following [this](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-validation-example/) tutorial. Though, my code is in Koltin unlike the tutorial.

My code is as follows -

**Entity class**

```
@Entity
class PodcastEntity(@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @NotNull
                    var id: Long = 0,
                    @field:NotEmpty(message = "Please provide an author")
                    var author: String,
                    @field:NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a title")
                    var title: String,
                    @field:NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a description")
                    var description: String,
                    @field:NotEmpty(message = "Please provide category one")
                    var categoryOne: String,
                    @field:NotEmpty(message = "Please provide category two")
                    var categoryTwo: String,
                    var filePath: String = "")
```

My post method is like this in the `controller` -

```
@PostMapping("details")
fun addPodcast(@Valid @RequestBody podcastEntity: PodcastEntity) {
    podcastService.addPodcast(podcastEntity)
}
```

My POST request in postman is like this -

```
{
    "author" : "me 3",
    "title" : "File three",
    "description" : "this is a test desc"
}
```

Since `categoryOne` and `categoryTwo` are missing and I have not handled the exception on my own, my console should show `MethodArgumentNotValidException` according to the tutorial. However, I'm getting no such exception. What I'm getting is a `HttpMessageNotReadableException` exception -

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.krtkush.test.entities.PodcastEntity] value failed for JSON property categoryOne due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter categoryOne which is a non-nullable type; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.krtkush.test.entities.PodcastEntity] value failed for JSON property categoryOne due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter categoryOne which is a non-nullable type  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 1] (through reference chain: com.krtkush.test.entities.PodcastEntity["categoryOne"])]
```

I'm unable to understand where I'm going wrong. Some help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Damian's SO link in his answer, I found the first answer really helpful and more appropriate. I modified the @Entitiy class by making the required fields nullable (`?`) like this -

```
@Entity
class PodcastEntity(@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
                    var id: Long = 0,
                    @field:NotEmpty(message = "Please provide an author")
                    var author: String?,
                    @field:NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a title")
                    var title: String?,
                    @field:NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a description")
                    var description: String?,
                    @field:NotEmpty(message = "Please provide category one")
                    var categoryOne: String?,
                    @field:NotEmpty(message = "Please provide category two")
                    var categoryTwo: String?,
                    var filePath: String = "")
```

This makes sure that the code throws `MethodArgumentNotValidException` in all three cases - 1. Empty argument 2. `null` argument 3. Missing argument

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this issue by providing `HttpMessageNotReadableException` handler
and then checking if the main cause is `MissingKotlinParameterException`.

After that, you can provide custom validation error.

```kotlin
    @ExceptionHandler
    override fun handleMessageNotReadableException(
        exception: HttpMessageNotReadableException,
        request: NativeWebRequest
    ): ResponseEntity<Problem> {
        // workaround
        val cause = exception.cause
        if (cause is MissingKotlinParameterException) {
            val violations = setOf(createMissingKotlinParameterViolation(cause))
            return newConstraintViolationProblem(exception, violations, request)
        }
        return create(Status.BAD_REQUEST, UnableToReadInputMessageProblem(), request)
    }

    private fun createMissingKotlinParameterViolation(cause: MissingKotlinParameterException): Violation {
        val name = cause.path.fold("") { jsonPath, ref ->
            val suffix = when {
                ref.index > -1 -> "[${ref.index}]"
                else -> ".${ref.fieldName}"
            }
            (jsonPath + suffix).removePrefix(".")
        }
        return Violation(name, "must not be null")
    }
```

This way you get get nice output with proper constraint error.

You may try to declare `@ExceptionHandler` for `MissingKotlinParameterException` directly.

Answer based on question [Spring not null validation throwing HttpMessageNotReadableException instead of MethodArgumentNotValidException in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54797207/spring-not-null-validation-throwing-httpmessagenotreadableexception-instead-of-m)

Comment: The linked question's first answer was more accurate to what I was looking for. Thanks!